# How can I slice one plane from a VectorPlot3D to get a stream plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am analyzing a system of ODEs in three equations/three variables, and I have a linearized system
$$\begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y' \\ z' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}.$$

I have plotted this in 3D using `VectorPlot3D` and I would like to get slices, i.e., stream plot representations of the XY, XZ, and YZ planes. If the equations were completely decoupled I would just make three separate plots using the StreamPlot` -- however, the equations for $x'$ and $y'$ are only partially decoupled, so I am not sure how to get a 2-Dimensional stream plot on the XZ plane, as I can only specify two variables.

So, is there a way to input my 3D vector field equations and get out 2D slices on certain planes? I think I can do this using either the `ViewPoint` or `ViewProjection` options, but I am not sure how to use them.

Here is my `VectorPlot3D` code for reference.

```
VectorPlot3D[{-x - y, 2 y, z}, {x, 0.0, 1.2}, {y, 0.0, 1.2}, {z, 0.0, 1.2},
  Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> 
    {Style["x", Bold, FontSize -> 24], Style["y", Bold, FontSize -> 24],
     Style["z", Bold, FontSize -> 24]},
  VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  VectorPoints -> 5,
  VectorScale -> {0.1, .7, None}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the definition of the XZ plane is that $y=0$ for all coordinates lying on the plane. So, I can plot the XZ plane as
`StreamPlot[{-x, z}, {x, 0, 1.2}, {z, 0, 1.2}]`. And this is exactly the same as taking a slice of the 3D vector field.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for starters, the $x$ and $y$ solutions are independent of $z$.  Also, I understand there is symmetry, but it is helpful to plot the negative values of the variables, as well (since $(x>0,y<0) \textrm{ or } (x<0,y>0)$ has different behavior than both negative or both positive:

```
StreamPlot[{-x - y, 2 y}, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, Axes -> False, 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["x", Bold, FontSize -> 24], Style["y", Bold, FontSize -> 24]}, StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  StreamScale -> {0.1, .7, None}]
```

[image]

Here is a view looking at the $xz$-plane, with your code and very minor adjustments,

```
 VectorPlot3D[{-x - y, 2 y, z}, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, {z, -1.2, 1.2}, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["x", Bold, FontSize -> 24], Style["y", Bold, FontSize -> 24], 
   Style["z", Bold, FontSize -> 24]}, 
   VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow", VectorPoints -> 5, 
   VectorScale -> {0.1, .7, None}, ViewPoint -> Front]
```

The main "addition" is `ViewPoint->Front`, which I just looked up in the documentation.

[image]

Comment: Well, this doesn't really answer my question (how to plot the XZ plane of the 3D field). But I figured that out. However, I feel like I should say--I am aware of the behavior of the point already, I was just trying to get some good visualization images. The eigenvalues of the matrix reflect that the point is a saddle, and for the problem I am modeling, negative values are not allowed as inputs--I should have stated this in the question but I did not think it was relevant.

Comment: Okay, I did not mean to presume anything about what you already know about the problem.  It seems to me that you fully understand the problem, and are exploring how to use *Mathematica*.   Did you use viewpoint, or something else?  Okay, I see your answer posted.  Yes, "negative values not allowed" is relevant, mostly because to attempt an answer, we could only guess at information not provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
SliceVectorPlot3D[{-x - y, 2 y, z}, 
"CenterPlanes", 
 {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

or

```
SliceVectorPlot3D[{-x - y, 2 y, z}, 
"ZStackedPlanes", 
 {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

or....

```
SliceVectorPlot3D[{-x - y, 2 y, z}, 
 InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}],
 {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

[image]